# VBA get address for last empty row and copy

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a worksheet where the date is stored in columns, I want to write a macro which cuts the data and paste the data in row B. Please see picture attached.

I have already written this code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng, copy_paste_range As Range


    Set rng = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlToRight))

    For Each r In rng

        Range(Range(r.Address), Range(r.Address).End(xlDown)).Copy
        'last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastLine = Range(("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2).Select
        LastLine.Paste

    Next r

End Sub
```

However I always want to leave 1 row empty when I copy the data from every column but I always get an error for:

```
LastLine = Range(("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2).Select
            LastLine.Paste
```

Can anyone assist ? If you look in the picture I am trying to cut-copythe data from C2:C5 and past it to [image]B12:B15

Comment: Replace `Range(Range(r.Address), Range(r.Address).End(xlDown)).Copy
        'last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastLine = Range(("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2).Select
        LastLine.Paste` with `Range(Range(r.Address), Range(r.Address).End(xlDown)).Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(2)` all in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dimmed the rng as a variant and you should dim r as range as well

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlToRight))

    For Each r In rng.Cells
        Range(Range(r.Address), Range(r.Address).End(xlDown)).Copy Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    Next r

End Sub
```